# Writing a program that determines a prime number

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that asks the user to enter a number, then I need to create a method called `isPrime` to create the calculation and print out the result in main. I'm sure it's something small that I'm missing, but I can't get it to produce an accurate result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter number: ");
    int num = s.nextInt();

    if (isPrime(num) == true) {
        System.out.println("Number is prime");
    } else if (isPrime(num) == false) {
        System.out.println("Number is not prime");
    }    
}  

public static boolean isPrime(int num){
    for(int i = 2; i <= num/2; i++) {
        if (num%i != 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Look at your 'if (num%i != 0)'. For num = 15, the first iteration will produce true although it is not a prime. Think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The isPrime(int num) method may need to check if `num % i == 0` instead of if `num % i != 0` because many non-prime numbers will pass the condition and return true.

As an example, if `isPrime(9)` is called, the conditional will check if 9 % 2 != 0, which is true, and the method will say that 9 is prime when it's not.

As a result, you could try changing the method to something like this:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int num)
{
    for(int i = 2; i <= num/2; i++)
    {
        if (num%i==0)
        {
         return false;
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an `if` and `else` (don't retest your boolean condition in the first case). And don't test for `== true` in an `if`. This

```
if(isPrime(num) == true)
{
    System.out.println("Number is prime");
}
else if(isPrime(num) == false)
{
    System.out.println("Number is not prime");
}
```

Should just be

```
if (isPrime(num)) {
    System.out.println("Number is prime");
} else {
    System.out.pritnln("Number is not prime");
}
```

***or* even** something like

```
System.out.print("Number is ");
if (!isPrime(num)) {
    System.out.print("not ");
}
System.out.println("prime");
```

If you want to put the braces on their own lines go ahead. As for your `isPrime` method; you have your return conditions reversed (and the test as well). Also we can optimize it a bit. Unroll the first even test, because then we can skip every other element. Also we only need to test to the square root of the input number. Like,

```
public static boolean isPrime(int num) {
    if (num == 2) {
        return true; // two is prime.
    }
    if (num < 1 || num % 2 == 0) {
        return false; // all other even numbers are not prime.
    }
    for(int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i += 2) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
     }
     return true;
}
```

Comment: You also need to check for numbers less than one. Any integer zero or less is not a prime number.

Comment: @flakes Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your "if (num%i!=0)" condition to if(num % i == 0)

See the following code:

```
public class Prime {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int num = 29;
    boolean flag = false;
    for(int i = 2; i <= num/2; ++i)
    {
        // condition for nonprime number
        if(num % i == 0)
        {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!flag)
        System.out.println(num + " is a prime number.");
    else
        System.out.println(num + " is not a prime number.");
}
}
```